# Failed to initialize anaconda directory

Tags: anaconda3

i've been trying to install anaconda but whenever i try to install it just says "Failed to initialize Anaconda directories", so the installation can't be completed. I tried to reinstall the program but still get that an error message. does anyone here have an idea on what to do?